# Another FTP daemon is already runing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, ftp

Me descargué xampp en ubuntu 20.04 todo bien hasta que se ejecuta ProFTPD y dice que ya hay otro FTP ejecutandose, no puedo encontrar la causa de esto y me serviría mucho si me pueden ayudar.

```
$: sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
    
    Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.8-0...
    XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
    XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
    XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
    XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already runing.
```

[image: Acá se puede ver que tengo los servicios corriendo menos ProFTPD]

Acá se puede ver que tengo los servicios corriendo menos ProFTPD.

Ya de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estas ejecutando Xampp con el servicio FTP incluido, debes tener ya instalado y funcionando otro servicio de FTP. Debes verificar cual es y detenerlo o desinstalarlo.

Podría ser VSFTPD, si es asi, debe existir un archivo en `/etc/vsftpd.conf`. Si es asi puedes desisntalarlo con el siguiente comando.

```
sudo apt-get remove vsftpd
```

Si no es ese, puedes avaeriguar cual es si ejecutas el comando:

```
ftp localhost
```

El comando retornara el mensaje de bienvenida del FTP que generalemente dice que aplicacion es:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
```

Comment: es curioso porque me dice que el que estoy usando es ProFTPD

Comment: ProFTPD es el que viene configurado con XAMPP, pero puede existir otro previamente funcionando que interfiera al usar el mismo puerto. Tienes respuesta al ejecutar `ftp localhost`?